# How to access all gcloud app engine instances?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

I am actually deploying a Django app in App Engine Flexible for the first time, so to not have a high bill, I want to delete all the instances that were created when I used  `gcloud app deploy` (2 instances are created every time)

By checking in the console I only find two instances, and only when I delete them that the two instances before them appear.

I tried then running `gcloud app instances list`, but I still see only the last two instances.

Do you have a method to see all the instances for a given project in App Engine?

Comment: Appengine flex always requires at least 1 (default is 2 however) instance(s) to be running so fully shutting it down is not possible even when no traffic is incoming. Is there a reason you are still using appengine flex instead of cloud run? Cloud run will scale to 0 (and not keep old instances around infinitely even if no traffic is assigned to it).

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml? Confirming the previous comment, the [default amount of instances is set at 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#services:~:text=automatic%20scaling%20settings.-,min_num_instances,-The%20minimum%20number).